# How to get data out when tensor doesn't provide numpy()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've got a tensor which is provided as `data` parameter by keras to my custom model's `train_step`. It seems to be handled just fine by the `self(data, training=True)` call. For evaluation of result I want to look at the data though.

When I print it out, I get:

```
Tensor("IteratorGetNext:0", shape=(120, 1080), dtype=float32)
```

But I can't seem to get the data itself. `data.numpy()` raises exception `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'`.

I don't have a session available at that point for `eval()` either. How can I get the data out?

Comment: Is the data coming from `tf.data.Datasets`?

Comment: @yudhiesh The data is passed to `fit` as x, from a generator doing `yield (numpy_array,)`

Comment: try passing `execute_eagerly=True` in `model.compile()`

Comment: @NicolasGervais `run_eagerly`, but yes, that worked, thanks. Wanna post the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access tensor values as NumPy arrays in graph mode. This data is "leaving" Python and therefore inaccessible ([read more](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/intro_to_graphs)). In order to access the tensors, you can **run eagerly** ([read more](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager)) like this:

```
model.compile(... run_eagerly=True)
```